# Express js "res.append" Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications

In my express project I call "res.append" for set several cookies in same request. But I got an error like this "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.".
Can anybody find out the problem and also give a solution or tell other better way?

My code is as follows:

```
var setCookie = function(res, key, value, hrs, callback) {
    if (typeof value === 'number'){value = value.toString(); }
    if (typeof value === 'object'){value = JSON.stringify(value); }
    var c;
    if (hrs === 0) {
        c = cookie.serialize(key, value, {httpOnly: true, path: '/', signed: true});
    }
    else {
        c = cookie.serialize(key, value, {
            maxAge: 3600 * hrs,
            httpOnly: true,
            path: '/',
            signed: true
        });
    }
    res.append('Set-Cookie', c);
    callback(1);
};

var setLoginCookies = function(req, res, uaid, uuid, locale, trusted, callback) {
    //sid
    console.log('setLoginCookies:sid');
    setCookie(res, 'sid', req.sessionID, 168, function () {
        //uuid
        console.log('setLoginCookies:uuid');
        setCookie(res, 'uid', uuid, 168, function () {
            //locale
            console.log('setLoginCookies:locale');
            setCookie(res, 'locale', locale, 0, function () {
                callback(1);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Error:

```
GET / 200 748.366 ms - 5209
setLoginCookies:sid
D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:97
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:700:10)
    at ServerResponse.append (D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:670:15)
    at setCookie (D:\mongodb\Project\com_modules\ran-doratupaala\app\libs\libCom.js:88:9)
    at Object.setLoginCookies (D:\mongodb\Project\com_modules\ran-doratupaala\app\libs\libCom.js:123:5)
    at D:\mongodb\Project\com_modules\ran-doratupaala\index.js:101:28
    at D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\express-session\session\store.js:43:5
    at D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:437:9
    at handleCallback (D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:95:12)
    at D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:763:5
    at D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:795:13
    at Callbacks.emit (D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:94:3)
    at null.messageHandler (D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:235:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\mongodb\Project\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:259:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
16 Jun 19:58:05 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: To exactly know what is happening when a request arrives we would also need the code around the sections mentioned in your stack trace: 
    `setCookie at com_modules\ran-doratupaala\app\libs\libCom.js:88:9`, `Object.setLoginCookies at com_modules\ran-doratupaala\app\libs\libCom.js:123:5` & `com_modules\ran-doratupaala\index.js:101:28`. It seems there's already something sent back to the client before you try to set the headers

Answer (score 1):

Show the context how you call the setLoginCookies function?

Looks like something, maybe cookie.serialize might be async, causing javascript to continue execution after setLoginCookies and not wait for it to complete.

Also, why not use chaining pattern of

```
cookiez(res)
    .set('sid', req.sessionID, 168)
    .set('uid', uuid, 168)
    .set('locale', locale, 0);
```

Comment: Yeah I totally agree here. Using the callback pattern in an non-async case doesn't make sense and makes the code look worse than it actually is!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you issue a res.append multiple times. In my understanding a response can be given only once.

Comment: No, it's only the case for `res.send`. with `res.append` you add header information [see the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.append).